# EF code first: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-2000

I have issue with EF code first, when I am trying to insert a new record into a table I receive the message.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '' when
> IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Any idea why I am getting the error?

I am using following code:

```
 public void SaveNewResponse()
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var newResponse = new Response()
                {
                    lngRequestLineID = 1001233,
                    memXMLResponse = "test Response",
                    fAdhoc = false,
                };
            context.tblResponses.Add(newResponse);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And here is my mapping

```
 public class tblResponsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<tblRespons>
{
    public tblResponsMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.lngResponseLineID});
                        
        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.lngResponseLineID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.lngRequestLineID);

                 // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("tblResponses");
        this.Property(t => t.lngResponseLineID).HasColumnName("lngResponseLineID");
        this.Property(t => t.lngRequestLineID).HasColumnName("lngRequestLineID");
        this.Property(t => t.fAdhoc).HasColumnName("fAdhoc");
        this.Property(t => t.memXMLResponse).HasColumnName("memXMLResponse");
  
    }
}
```

Comment: as always, I post the question and found the answer minutes after..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,
I have found it.
The database has been set up correctly, but my mapping has been incorrect.

```
public class tblResponsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<tblRespons>
{
public tblResponsMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => new { t.lngResponseLineID});

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.lngResponseLineID)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); <-- here

    this.Property(t => t.lngRequestLineID);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("tblResponses");
    this.Property(t => t.lngResponseLineID).HasColumnName("lngResponseLineID");
    this.Property(t => t.lngRequestLineID).HasColumnName("lngRequestLineID");
    this.Property(t => t.fAdhoc).HasColumnName("fAdhoc");
    this.Property(t => t.memXMLResponse).HasColumnName("memXMLResponse");
}
}
```

Comment: This solution works when you get this error upgrading from EF 4 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change mapping code, instead you should change this line:

```
lngRequestLineID = 1001233
```

to this:

```
lngRequestLineID = 0
```

In my expirence decorating de Id entity's property with [KeyAttribute] is enought.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this error when I was adding a relationship to EF core entity model by pointing it to an entity model that was fetched outside of the current context and was no longer being tracked.  I was doing this to avoid an extra read operation which initially felt awkward to me.

```
public static void AddMatches(List<Match> matches, Profile p)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            match.Profile = p;
            db.Match.Add(match);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I solved it by doing another read operation. After consulting the Microsoft docs [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0#entity-states), I was reassured that this is relatively normal especially in the MVC world.  Fix:

```
public static void AddMatches(List<Match> matches, Profile p)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        var profile = db.Profile.Find(p.ProfileId);
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            match.Profile = profile;
            db.Match.Add(match);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```